# Scrollbar contains contents belong to web page after refresh

Tags: html, css, frontend, hexo

I am building a blog website driven by Hexo. After I changed the font-size and resized the left panel, the vertical scrollbar contains some contents belong to the blog article contents when refresh the webpage every time. However, when I change to another web-tab(like wiki or something else) and back to the blog page tab, the scrollbar turns working normally.
I have no idea why this happened. And I am trying to fix this issue. The weird scrollbar capture is provided below. The pink element is scroll thumb and others are the elements should belong to blog article content.
I will appreciate if anything would be helpful.

[image: the scrollbar picture]